# How to iterate through greendao list?

Tags: android, greendao

Please help, i'm kinda newbie when it comes to android app with a database.

In Greendao documentation there's a point of having this code:

```
List users = usersDao.queryBuilder().orderDesc(Properties.Id).list();
```

But somehow, it is not documented well on how to exactly get the values of rows from that query builder? or is there even a point where I could only get the first row, or last row from the database?

Thanks in advance for someone who will help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Entity class are similar to all other classes. So `greendao` generates properties for all rows and you can access them as you access all others properties form "normal" classes.

To access `Id` property of `UserEntity` you can use getter `user.getId()`.

From this query you are getting list of users. You can access it as you are accessing any other list in `Java`.

To get first user from database you can use code similar to:

```
List<User> users = usersDao.queryBuilder().orderDesc(...).limit(1).list();
if (users.size() < 1) return null;
return users.get(0);
```

To get last user I suggest to use similar query with reversed order:

```
List<User> users = usersDao.queryBuilder().orderAsc(...).limit(1).list();
if (users.size() < 1) return null;
return users.get(0);
```

If your query returns only one unique entity you can use `unique` method:

```
User user = usersDao.queryBuilder().where(...).unique();
```

You don't need to build these queries all the time. You can build it once, and then reuse it:

```
private Query<User> mSomeUserQuery;
...
// initialization
mSomeUserQuery = usersDao.queryBuilder().where(...).build();
// usage
User user = mSomeUserQuery.forCurrentThread().unique();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! :D I'm sorry i can't vote up yet because i don't have enough reputation for vote up! thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Greendao lists are not different to other lists in Java. You just have to google how to iterate through lists. Result: [Ways to iterate over a List in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18410035/ways-to-iterate-over-a-list-in-java)

But here is the answer with the example to get the name value from an user:

```
for(User user : users){
     String name = user.getName();
 }
```