# Java Tuple/Pair

Tags: java, arraylist, tuples, keyvaluepair

My Pair class:

```
public class Pair<o,t> {

      private o one;
      private t two;

      public Pair(o one, t two) {
        this.one = one;
        this.two = two;
      }

      public o getO() { 
          return one;
      }

      public void setO(o one) {
          this.one = one;
      }

      public t getT() {
          return two;
      }

      public void setT(t two) {
          this.two= two;
      }
}
```

In my main application I fill a list with the pair object:

```
List<Pair<Integer, String>> test = new ArrayList<Pair<Integer, String>>();
Pair<Integer, String> pair;

pair.setO(1);
pair.setT("A");
test.add(pair);

pair.setO(2);
pair.setT("B");
test.add(pair);
```

I want to be able to get the integer value only by list index, eg. for-loop to write out A, B, etc. How would I do that? Is there a simpler way of doing such a thing in Java?

Comment: when you iterate over the list you iterate over Pair, so use .getT()

Comment: "*Is there a simpler way of doing such a thing in java?*" simpler than what? Also in what meaning simpler? If you don't want to use loops you can use streams but I am not sure if that is what you want.

Comment: Just a quick note, but the Java Naming Conventions state that accessors and mutators (getters and setters) should be of the form `(get/set)<field name in camel case>`. For example, in your case, `getTwo` and `setTwo`.

Comment: What do you mean by integer value?

Comment: Do you perhaps want to sort added Pairs to order them according to value of integer `o` and after they are sorted print value of `t`? Your question is kind of vague. We don't actually know what problem you are facing so it is hard to figure out how to help you...

Comment: Thanks guys! Good input that led me onto the right direction. also thanks for outlining the naming convention ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ways to iterate over a List in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18410035/ways-to-iterate-over-a-list-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Braj suggested, you can use a for-each loop.

```
for(Pair<Integer, String> p : test ){
    System.out.println(p.getT());
}
```

However, because of the way you are adding objects, the output will actually be:

```
B
B
```

This is because when you add an object to the ArrayList, you are actually adding a **reference** to that object, so when you modify it, you will modify the one stored in the ArrayList as well. **A separate copy of the object is not created!** You need to construct a new Pair object for this to work as you intend.

Another note: you haven't used a constructor to initialize `pair`, so javac will yell at you.

To get around both of theses errors, change your code to this:

```
List<Pair<Integer, String>> test = new ArrayList<Pair<Integer, String>>();
test.add(new Pair<Integer, String>(1, "A"));
test.add(new Pair<Integer, String>(2, "B"));
for(Pair<Integer, String> p : test ){
    System.out.println(p.getT());
}
```

Comment: just figured that one. thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1):

> for-loop to write out A, B, etc.  How would I do that?

Use [The For-Each Loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) for Iterating over a collection.

```
for(Pair<Integer, String> pair : test ){
     System.out.println(pair.getT());
}
```

Comment: thanks @Braj ! good stuff

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get by index:

```
int i = ... ;
t theT = test.get(i).getT();
o theO = test.get(i).getO();
```

Also a bit of advice: capitalize your generic types always, makes for less confusion because names that start with a lower case letter are generally objects and not a class/type.