# Using for loop arraylist in Java

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

Can someone please let me know how to use `for` loop for `ArrayList`? 
 
 I've code as below

```
m.value1= new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(11,12));
m1.value2 = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5));
```

`for` loop should take values as (11,1), (11,2),(11,3)... (12,1),(12,2)..

Comment: No, we won't because SO is not here to do your homework. If you can show us what you tried and why and how it is not working, then we can help you solve a *specific* problem.

Comment: Asking for a ready solution is not a good way of learning.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ways to iterate over a List in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18410035/ways-to-iterate-over-a-list-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
m.value1= Arrays.asList(11,12);
m1.value2 = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5); 

for(Integer i : m.value1) {
   for(Integer j : m1.value2){
      System.out.println("("+i+","+j+")");
   }
}
```

Comment: when I use that it says " cannot convert from element type Object to Integer"

Comment: What is the type of m.value1 or m1.value2 in your code?

Comment: It is because Arrays.asList(11,12) returns a List, which then tried to convert to Integer, because of your declaration new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(11,12)); I think the declaration should be just Arrays.asList(11,12));. Try the edited version.

Comment: If it does not work, can you, please, add the declaration code of m.value1 and m.value2?

Comment: I declared incorrecly. Now it worked :) Thank you. public ArrayList<Integer> value1 ;
public ArrayList<Integer> value2;  --> It worked