# How to access model attribute fields in JSP scriptlet?

Tags: java, spring, jsp

In my controller I have code like this:

```
List<FeesReceiptIntegrationModel> FRIList = feesReceiptIntegrationService.listInstituteWiseCollectionSummary(model, request);

model.addAttribute("FRIList", FRIList);
```

I want to access this FRIList and its fields in Scriptlet of JSP page.
I tried something like this:

```
String fcash = request.getParameter(FRIList.cashamount);
```

but it does not work.

```
List myMap = (ArrayList) request.getAttribute("FRIList.cashamount");
```

I don't want to access this via JSTL tags but I would like to access this only in scriptlet.

Can anybody tell me how this can be achieved?

Comment: You put in model list "FRIList", so you can get it in jsp like that: `List myMap = (ArrayList) request.getAttribute("FRIList");` and than do what you want with this list.

Comment: i am access like this  List myMap = (ArrayList) request.getAttribute("FRIList.cashamount");     System.out.println("ooooo oo "+ myMap);         but till now i can't access  ..... myMap show null value..

Comment: @ManojSharma I suppose you use the `spring` framework . Are you using any view templates for your front-end ?

Comment: For front end i am using jsp,jstl..

Answer (score 1):

Using scriplets is a bad idea. Try to avoid using java codes inside JSP page.

You can use JSTL [c:forEach](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/forEach.html) for your purpose

Simple example

```
<c:forEach items="${FRIList}" begin="0" end="1" var="test">
${test.cashamount}
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: I know but i can't resolve my issue without using scriptlet ..have you any idea ...???

Comment: @ManojSharma iterate over the list

Comment: @ManojSharma http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18410035/ways-to-iterate-over-a-list-in-java

Answer (score 0):

You cant print the values in the list as it is, you need to iterate them after you get the list from the `model`. As said,

> I don't want to access this via JSTL tags but I would like to access this only in scriptlet

```
<%  List<FeesReceiptIntegrationModel > myMap = (ArrayList<FeesReceiptIntegrationModel >) request.getAttribute("FRIList");
    for(FeesReceiptIntegrationModel obj : myMap  ){
    obj.getcashamount(); // your getter method here
    }
%>
```

but it is not advisable to use the `scriptlets`, please have a look at [How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)

Comment: it gives compile time error Object cannot be converted to FeesReceiptIntegrationModel..

Comment: Check my update , you need to cast the object to the bean class