# Invalid Assignment Operator

Tags: java

I'm getting

> < invalid assignment operator

in this code snippet

```
int length=0;
int i=0;
for ( Iterator<String> t_Number = keyset.iterator(); t_Number.hasNext()&& i<length;)
{
  String key = (String)t_Number.next();
  row = sheet.createRow(rownum++);
  Object[] objArr = (Object[])excel_data.get(key);
  int cellnum = 0;
  Object[] array;
  length = (array = objArr).length; continue;
  Object obj = array[i];
  Cell cell = row.createCell(cellnum++);
  if ((obj instanceof Double)) {
    cell.setCellValue(((Double)obj).doubleValue());
  } else {
    cell.setCellValue((String)obj);
  }
  i++;
}
```

Can some one please let me know to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The structure of a `for` loop is:

```
for (initialization; termination; increment)
```

Your increment step is `i < length`, which isn't a statement which modifies anything.

Assuming you want to check for that condition as well, you should use `&&` instead of putting it in the increment step:

```
for(Iterator<String> t_Number = keyset.iterator(); 
    t_Number.hasNext() && i<length;/* no increment */)
```

If you do this, make sure you do something inside the loop (or add an actual increment step) which changes `keyset` or `i` so that the termination condition will eventually be `false`.

In response to your update, the new problem comes from this line:

```
length = (array = objArr).length; continue;
```

`continue` means to skip the rest of that repetition of the loop; it will just increment, go back to the start of the block, and keep running. Since you call `continue` unconditionally, it will always be executed, and nothing in the loop after it can ever be reached. Either remove the `continue`, or put an `if(/* some condition */)` before it.

Answer (score 0):

In the last of the 3 portions of the `if` statement, Java expects a statement, but all you have is an expression, `i<length`.  The compiler error I get is "not a statement".

If you intended this to be another condition to keep iterating, then add it to the condition (middle) portion.

```
for (Iterator<String> t_Number = keyset.iterator(); t_Number.hasNext() &&  i<length; )
```

(It's assumed that something in the actual body of your code is calling `t_Number.next()` and moving forward in the iteration.)

Comment: i added code snippet can you please advise me now iam getting unrecahable code

Answer (score 0):

Your

```
i<length
```

is unnecessary.

Have a read of [Ways to iterate over a list in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18410035/ways-to-iterate-over-a-list-in-java).