# How to get the values of List<String> using iterator

Tags: collections

How can i get the values of comp1 and comp2 .I have tried using iterator but it is giving me exception.

Update:If i have to get the values in another class than how can i do that

```
public class Complex {


 public List<String>comp1;
 public List<String>comp2;

public List<String> getComp2() {
    return comp2;
}

public void setComp2(List<String> comp2) {
    this.comp2 = comp2;
}

public List<String> getComp1() {
    return comp1;
}

public void setComp1(List<String> comp1) {
    this.comp1 = comp1;
}
```

}

Comment: code looks good to me. after calling the setter you can call the getter.

Comment: The code example which you post here does not help so much. Maybe you mean `for (String value : comp1) { System.out.println(value); }` (which is internally using the iterator.

Comment: In general, take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18410035/ways-to-iterate-over-a-list-in-java?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

```
Iterator<String> it = comp1.getIterator();
while(it.hasNext()) {
   //do something with it
   it.next();
}
```

Same for comp2.

Comment: What if i have to get values in another class,then how should i call ?

Comment: Your get method returnes you the List and you can then iterate it in your "another class".