# How to break elements in a string and put into a numerical array

Tags: java, arrays, string, integer, primes

The following java code prints the set of prime numbers below the given numbers as a string! how can i get those numbers in the string into an integer array?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

class Prime
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x = s.nextInt();
        int i =0;
        int num =0;
        //Empty String
        String  primeNumbers = "";

        for (i = 1; i <= x; i++)
        {
            int counter=0;
            for(num =i; num>=1; num--)
            {
                if(i%num==0)
                {
                    counter = counter + 1;
                }
            }
            if (counter ==2)
            {
                //Appended the Prime number to the String
                primeNumbers = primeNumbers + i + " ";
            }
        }

        System.out.println(primeNumbers);
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split a string in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the type of `primeNumbers` to the desired container, like: `ArrayList<Integer>`.

And, instead of using the `+` operator, append **items** to the collection with the `add` method.

Like so:

**Initialization:**

```
ArrayList<Integer> primeNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

**Append new items:**

```
primeNumbers.add(i);
```

And don't forget to add an import to the `ArrayList` class:

`import java.util.ArrayList`

Comment: Thanx alot! :) how can get 3 numbers frm the array list so that their sum is the number that i enter? that would be a great help

Comment: @Amal Happy to help. First, If this answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted. Second, I don't really understand your next question. Could you please edit and add an example of the desired result?

Comment: i meant if we give  input 65! i need to get 3 numbers  from the arraylist thats sums to 65 and display them! eg- 23 ,31 and 11

Comment: @Amal Read more about ArrayList and iterating through it with a 'foreach' loop, for example. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18410035/ways-to-iterate-over-a-list-in-java.

Comment: i don't understand how to do please help me i am less used to arraylists!

Comment: @Amal Calm down. This isn't rocket-science. :) You have the tutorial above for iterating through lists, and I can see you are comfortable with conditions. Put it all together + google = You will be OK. If you really try and don't get the desired result, feel free to post a second question, and show what you tried and what seems to be the problem.