# How to find the max value of any duplicate in an ArrayList

Tags: java, collections

I am currently writing  class that creates multiple hands containing card objects using arrayLists. I am trying to write a method that searches an arraylist (hand) and returns the largest pair of cards.

Here is what I have now but it is very inefficient:

```
public int findPairRank() {
    int one = 0, two = 0, three = 0, four = 0, five = 0, six = 0, seven = 0, eight = 0, nine = 0, ten = 0, eleven = 0, twelve = 0, thirteen = 0;

    // loops through every card rank and adds +1 if it exists in the hand
    for (int i = 0; i < cards.size(); i++) {
        if (cards.get(i).getRank() == 1)
            one++;
        if (cards.get(i).getRank() == 2)
            two++;
        if (cards.get(i).getRank() == 3)
            three++;
        if (cards.get(i).getRank() == 4)
            four++;
        if (cards.get(i).getRank() == 5)
            five++;
        if (cards.get(i).getRank() == 6)
            six++;
        if (cards.get(i).getRank() == 7)
            seven++;
        if (cards.get(i).getRank() == 8)
            eight++;
        if (cards.get(i).getRank() == 9)
            nine++;
        if (cards.get(i).getRank() == 10)
            ten++;
        if (cards.get(i).getRank() == 11)
            eleven++;
        if (cards.get(i).getRank() == 12)
            twelve++;
        if (cards.get(i).getRank() == 13)
            thirteen++;
    }
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    if (one == 2)
        list.add(1);
    if (two == 2)
        list.add(2);
    if (three == 2)
        list.add(3);
    if (four == 2)
        list.add(4);
    if (five == 2)
        list.add(5);
    if (six == 2)
        list.add(6);
    if (seven == 2)
        list.add(7);
    if (eight == 2)
        list.add(8);
    if (nine == 2)
        list.add(9);
    if (ten == 2)
        list.add(10);
    if (eleven == 2)
        list.add(11);
    if (twelve == 2)
        list.add(12);
    if (thirteen == 2)
        list.add(13);

    int max = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        if (list.get(i) > max)
            max = list.get(i);
    }
    if (max > 0)
        return max;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: You could trivially implement a multiset with `Map<Card, Integer>`, whether the Integer is the count. Then you could just iterate over it and find the largest count.

Comment: Do you mean the runtime inefficient, or is the code is bulky?

Comment: use array .....

Comment: @MeetTitan That the code is bulky! I feel like I could use a double nested array list to do it in far less code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because common card games only have 13 different card rankings, it is possible to avoid the use of Maps. You just need a frequency counter for rankings on an `int[13]` (or even `byte[13]`) temp array. Here is an example:

```
public int findPairRank() {
    int[] freq = new int[13];
    for (Card c: cards) { //assuming you use Card objects
        freq[c.getRank()]++;
    }

    for (int i = 12; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (freq[i] == 2) return i;
    }
    return -1; //no pair found
}
```

*Note that typically the number 2 card has the lowest ranking (in my example rank = 0) and the Ace the highest one (in my example rank for aces is 12). You can easily change the above according to your ranking design.

Comment: `freq[c.getRank()]++;` will rise a `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` when `c.getRank()` returns `13` since the `freq` array has a length of 13. Consequently, the last index value usable is `12`.

Comment: I noted that this is for 0-12; this is easy for the OP to change according to his reqs.

Comment: I do really like this answer since it uses an array to solve the problem which was my original intention!. Ill try this out and report back.

Comment: ok, as @davidxxx commented, I see you are using ranking for 1-13 and the example is for 0-12. Let me know if you experience difficulties to transform it to 1-13 (just some additions/subtractions on the indices and then return 0 instead of -1)

Comment: @Wiz Indeed, it is a good way to address the problem :)  @Konstantinos Chalkias instead of additions on the indexes I would rather declare a array of 14 elements `int[] freq = new int[14];` I find that it makes the code clearer and natural even if the first element is not used.

Comment: sure @davidxxx, that could also work too; less verbose!

Comment: @davidxxx & Konstantinos Chalkis It worked exactly how I wanted! I changed the int[] array to hold 14 values and i made the for loop that checks for frequency start at 13 and end at 1. Thanks so much guys!!! I couldnt figure this out for the life of me yesterday.

Comment: Thanks, don't forget to return 0 if a pair is not found

Comment: Thank you! I had a quick question actually @Konstantinos Chalkias. I am unfamiliar with using : in a for loop. Does this just mean that as long as there are more cards in the card set array list, it will keep running the loop?

Comment: Yes iterating over the whole list. Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18410035/ways-to-iterate-over-a-list-in-java

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** better use map counter solution. this algorithm works, but I would not use it. It looked nice at the beginning, until Zhong Yu pointed to a problem.

---

Sort cards in hand by value, then iterate until you find a pair

```
// copy items to new list to preserve initial order
List<Card> cards = new ArrayList(playerCards); 
// sort cards by rank value from high to low
Collections.sort(cards, rankComparator);

int counter = 1; // number of cards of same rank
for (int i = 1; i < cards.size(); i++) {
    if (cards.get(i).getRank() == cards.get(i-1).getRank()) {
        counter++; // if card has same rank as previous, inc counter
    } else { // if rank changed
        if (counter == 2) { // if we had pair, return its rank
           return cards.get(i-1).getRank();
        } else { // start again
           counter = 1;
        }
    }
}    
return counter == 2 ? cards.get(i-1).getRank() : 0;
```

Comment: Since we want to find max pair, we could look at the sorted list from n to 1. How about changing for loop like this, for ( int i = cards.size()-1; i>=0;i--)?

Comment: @exiter2000 I assume that comparator is in decreasing order, so it puts highest card first

Comment: it may return something more than a pair - 3 or 4 of a kind

Comment: @Adam, if it has reverse ordering comparator implemented, it totally make sense.

Answer (score 1):

The code seems ok but it is very cumbersome as your repeat many things that should not be.
In the loop you could use a Map to associate card number with occurrence.
In this way you avoid the long series of `if` statements.

The code could look like that:

```
    List<Card> cards = ...
    Map<Integer,Integer> occurrenceByNumber = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < cards.size(); i++) {
        Card card = cards.get(i);
        Integer occurrence = occurrenceByNumber.get(card.getRank());
        if (occurrence == null){
            occurrence = 1;
        }       
        else{
           occurrence++;
        }   
        occurrenceByNumber.put(card.getRank(), occurrence);        
    }


    Integer maxNumber = null;
    for (Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : occurrenceByNumber.entrySet()){
        int occurrence = entry.getValue();
        int number = entry.getKey();
        if ( occurrence == 2 && (maxNumber == null || number> maxNumber)  ){
            maxNumber = number;
        }
    }

    return maxNumber;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<Integer> hand = new ArrayList<Integer>(13);
for (int i = 0; i < cards.size(); i++) {
    int x = cards.get(i).getRank();
    if(x>0&&x<14) {
         hand.set(i-1, hand.get(i-1)+1)); //increment values
    }
}
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(int i=0; i<hand.size(); i++) {
     if(hand.get(i)==2) {
          list.add(i+1); //one will be at index 0, etc
     }
}

return Collections.max(list);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would approach this problem:

1) Sort the hand on card rank from greatest rank to least rank.

2) Iterate over the cards in the sorted hand, finding the !first! instance
   of when the next card's ranking is the same as this card's ranking.
     if (cards.get(i+1).getRank() == cards.get(i).getRank())

3) Done.

Note, the above code is NOT efficient!  You can make minor changes to retain card rankings between loop iterations to make the code even more efficient.