# How do I search an ArrayList of Objects

Tags: java, arraylist, contains

I am creating an ArrayList of `Account`s (an object) and the `Account` constructor is

```java
public Account(String name, int accNum, int balance)
{
    myName = name;
    myAccountNum = accNum;
    myBalance = balance;
}
```

I want to know how to check the ArrayList to determine if a given accountNumber exists in it, and if it does, `return true`

```java
private static ArrayList<Account> accounts = new ArrayList<Account>();
```

My initial thought was this, but I do not think that this works

```java
if(accounts.contains(tempAccNum))
{
    //executes code that I have
}
```

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: I am using java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the [Java ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains-java.lang.Object-), `contains` performs an object equality comparison. To use `.contains`, you would need to

1. Implement the `.equals()` method for the Account class, and have it check only the `this.myAccountNum` property against the account number of the input `Account`.
2. Create a dummy `Account` with the desired account number to pass into `contains`.

A better method would involve evaluating an iterator, and checking the account numbers at each step. Here I assume that `myAccountNum` is a public property of the `Account` class.

```
Iterator<E> it = Accounts.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Account acc = it.next();
    if(acc.myAccountNum == tempAccNum)
        return true;
}
```

For `ArrayList` specifically, using `.get` with an index is not too bad:

```
for(int index = 0; index < Accounts.size(); ++index) {
    if(Accounts.get(index).myAccountNum == tempAccNum)
        return true;
```

For other `List` types, using indices can be very poor.
[Ways to iterate over a list in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18410035/ways-to-iterate-over-a-list-in-java?rq=1)

Comment: when you say myAccountNum what do you mean by this?  And I cannot use iterators as this is a school project and my teacher is requiring that we use an arraylist of objects

Comment: @Hersh, you are required to state when you are asking homework questions. My answer does use an `ArrayList<Account>` -- that is what you said `Accounts` is. And you also gave us `myAccountNumber` in your question - it is a property of the `Account` class.

Comment: I didn't know that thanks for telling me.  It's for a lab we're doing and she's told us that we can go here if we need help so I did.  In terms of the second part of your statement, someone answered my original question below with the part that i need from your myAccountNum.  My friend today also explained to me how it works, but thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to make it simple by just implementing an `equals()` method for account class.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o){
  if(o==null)return false;
  if(o.getClass()!=this.getClass())return false;
  Account demo = (Account)o;
  if(!demo.myName.equals(this.myName))return false;
  if(demo.myAccountNum != this.myAccountNum)return false ;
  if(demo.myBalance = this.myBalance)return false ;
}
```

then use contains method

Answer (score 0):

First add getter for `accNum` in `Account` model

Then try this

```
public boolean containsAcc(int accno) {
    for(int i=0;i<accounts.size();i++) {
        if(accounts!= null && accounts.get(i).getMyAccountNum()==acno) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Here `getMyAccountNum()` is the getter declared in `Account` model(shown below)

Then check this

```
if(containsAcc(tempAccNum))
{
//your code
}
```

Your Account model should be like this

```
public class Account {
String myName;
int myAccountNum;
int myBalance;
public Account(String name, int accNum, int balance)
{
    this.myName = name;
    this.myAccountNum = accNum;
    this.myBalance = balance;
}

public int getMyAccountNum() {
    return myAccountNum;
}
}
```