# Different ways to iterate 2 dimensional array

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, multidimensional-array, foreach

I'm preparing for the Java OCA exam but there are several tricky questions about how iterates a multidimensional array. 
So, if I had this array and I wanted to iterate using the for and for-each loops what would all be ways to do it?
I usually used only these three:

```
int [][]matrix = {{3,4,5},{6,7,8},{9},{10,11,12}};

//First way
for (int [] a : matrix){
 for (int i =0; i<a.length;i++){
   //code
 }
}

//Second way
for (int []a: matrix){
 for (int i: a){
   //code
 }
}

//Third way
for (int i = 0; i<matrix.length; i++) {
 for (int j=0; j<matrix[a].length; j++) {
  //code
 }
}

//Fourth way???
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What exactly is your question? List-based answers "show me all ways to do xyz" are not too nice mostly. Do you have a use-case or something specific that is to be achieved?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ways to iterate over a list in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18410035/ways-to-iterate-over-a-list-in-java)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You missed the for, foreach combination:

```
for (int i = 0; i<matrix.length; i++) {
  for (int j: matrix[i]){
    // code
  }
}
```

You can also use `while` loops instead of `for`. Can you be more specific about the context, so we can help you properly with what you need?

Comment: If you want clarifications by the person asking a question this should be done in the comments of the question - an answer should be given after all clarification was done so that it actually is an answer to the intended question :)