# Java: contains and add?

Tags: java

Hi I am doing a poker game for my project. I have some problems figuring out how to test my `contains()` method. I know that you can type `.contains("KING of SPADES");` for example but it does not work with my parameter. So what should I write instead? The same problem is with `add2` I don't really know how to work with that (how to add a list and how to print it out) so can someone explain?

```
ArrayList<Card> PileOfCards;

public Pile(){
    PileOfCards = new ArrayList<Card>();
}

public void add(Card c){
    PileOfCards.add(c);
}

public void add2(List<Card> cards){
    PileOfCards.add((Card)cards);
}

public Boolean contains(Card c){
    return PileOfCards.contains(c);
}
```

Comment: Your `PileOfCards` contains `Card` objects. The `contains` method thus wants that you pass in cars, not `String`s. Thus, it does not work with `String`s. You can either create a new card with that name and override `equals` for `Card`s (and `hashCode`). Or you setup a `Map<String, Card>` which associates names with cards. Then you have a fast direct access. Also note that `contains` in `List`s is very slow. Consider using a `Set` for this.

Comment: so if I want to test my method what should I write?

Comment: Furthermore, your method `add2` is casting a List of Cards to a single Card. Does that compile??

Comment: Can you show the `Card` class?

Comment: @RobertKock actually it does, thats what I assumed that I have to write in the method

Comment: @RobertKock It compiles, because in theory, someone somewhere could write `public class BizarreCard extends Card implements List<Card>`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as your second question regards: Try this

```
public void add2(List<Card> cards)
{
  PileOfCards.addAll(cards);
}
```

This of course does not check eventual duplicates...

For the first question, we need your `Card` class.

Answer (score 0):

- About your "add2()" problem:

You should use the `addAll()` method to append a list to another (@see [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#addAll(java.util.Collection))) And remove the cast operator `(Card) cards`, you are trying to transform a list of cards into a single card...

- About the "contains()" method:

The `List.contains` method check if an object instance is included into a List, checking by references. So even if the parameter is a Card with the exact same attributes, it won't be considered as included in the list. Try to iterate over your list and check if the card title is the same as the one you are looping on (@see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18410035/ways-to-iterate-over-a-list-in-java)). This might not be the best solution, as @Zabuza presented some possible ways, but you should start with that for the moment.