# Write a while loop to output the integer values from 0 up to n exclusive

Tags: java

How can I write a while loop to output the integer values from 0 up to n exclusive.

The output should have five values per line, with values separated by a space. I can do it on the same line but, I am confused about the five values per line. Where am I supposed to add while loop to do it?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class While
{
   public static void main( String[] args)
   {
      Scanner scan = new Scanner( System.in);

      // constants

      // variables
      int n;
      int value;


      // program code
      value = 0;
      System.out.println( "Enter an integer ");
      n = scan.nextInt();
      if( n <=0){
         System.out.println( "Error");
      }else
         while ( value < n){
         System.out.print( value + " ");
         value = value + 1;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a `while` loop anywhere yet?

Comment: Or just take one of the 4 identical answers :P

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ways to iterate over a list in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18410035/ways-to-iterate-over-a-list-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the modulus operator to determine if `value` is a multiple of `5`, and if so, print a newline:

```
while (value < n){
     System.out.print(value + " ");         
     if(value %5 == 4) {
          System.out.println();
     }
     value = value + 1;
}
```

***Output:*** (With input of 10)

```
0 1 2 3 4 
5 6 7 8 9
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need a `System.out.println();` after every 5th element:

```
    while ( value < n){
        System.out.print( value + " ");
        value = value + 1;
        if (value % 5 == 0)
            System.out.println();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This one line of code will print five values per line, with values separated by a space: `System.out.print(value % 5 == 0 ? "\n" : " ");`

`\n` is new line character. In `print` method `\n` gives a line break. So if `(value % 5 == 0)` equals `true` this line prints a line break, otherwise it prints space.

Thus your `while loop` should be like this:

```
while (value < n) {
    System.out.print(value);
    value = value + 1;
    System.out.print(value % 5 == 0 ? "\n" : " ");
}
```