# How to store a resultSet in the list and iterate a list with properties of an entity in a HQL statement?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I would like to know what   below HQL statement  returns and how to iterate it,

```
String hql0="select distinct d.dept_name as Dept_Name "+
            " from com.gavs.beans.Department as d";

org.hibernate.query.Query q0 = session.createQuery(hql0);
List r0=q0.list();
```

Now I couldn't find how to iterate this list using for loop.  This is my problem.   Thank You.

Comment: have you tried using foreach loop? `for(Object obj: r0){}`

Comment: No. Can you give me the the complete statement of for(Object obj: ro){...}

Comment: For example, is it like this for (Object[] result : results) {
    Integer maxPrice = (Integer)result[0];
    Integer minPrice = (Integer)result[1];
    Long count = (Long)result[2];
}

Comment: Not really sure what your question is. You are asking how to iterate on a List ? That's not at all `hibernate` or `hql` related, it has nothing to do with `ResultSet` either. So is your question really "I have a `List`, how can I iterate on its content in Java" ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18410035/ways-to-iterate-over-a-list-in-java

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: Hi Finci, can you please tell me how to get the dept_name  using , for(Object obj:r0)?@Finci

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I iterated the list as shown below,

```
String hql0="select distinct d.dept_name as Dept_Name "+
            " from com.gavs.beans.Department as d";

org.hibernate.query.Query q0 = session.createQuery(hql0);
List r0=q0.getResultlist(); //Instead of using list(), I used getResultList()

for(Object o:r0)
{
System.out.println(o.toString());
}
```

This will  print all the department names of the entity Department.