# How can I show a specific field of of a class I made when displaying an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, field

I'm making a small program that simulates some of a bank's basic functions. I created a class `Branch` and used an ArrayList to hold `Branch` objects that the user would like to add. If I would like to specifically display all of the Branch names (one of the fields in the class) of each object contained in `ArrayList<Branch>`, would that be possible? Or is it better to create an array of strings that will hold each branch name? Currently, when I try to print out the ArrayList it outputs the pointer (I think) to the console.

I can put my code up upon request.

Comment: This might help you: [Ways to iterate over a list in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18410035/ways-to-iterate-over-a-list-in-java) - Oh, and an extra array just to hold the names is a **horrible** idea. Don't create redundant duplicated data without very good reasons.

Comment: You have to override `toString()` method in `Branch` class. And you have to iterate over list to print single element of list.

Comment: You should show us what your code is, we'll be easier to help

Answer (score 2):

You basically answered it yourself. You just iterate over the ArrayList, and do stuff **for each** object.

For example, in a for-each-loop:

```
List<Branch> branchList = new ArrayList<Branch>();
for (Branch branch : branchList ) {
    // iterates through all your objects contained in the list
    // use the object here
}
```

Of course there are many more ways to do this, as it was already pointed out in a comment.

Comment: Thank you!! Also, didn't know you could cycle through an ArrayList using that syntax. Awesome stuff!

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate over your array to get the objects data.
Here is some example with Java 8 streams:

```
List<Branch> branches = new ArrayList<Branch>();
// prints out the name of the object
branches.stream().map(branchName -> branch.getName()).forEach(System.out::println);
```

I found a nice blogpost which explains streams and how you can work with it. In my opinion the best way to work with Lists:
https://winterbe.com/posts/2014/07/31/java8-stream-tutorial-examples/