# The loop doesn't work - only the first element repeats

Tags: java, loops

Here is the code that reproduces the problem

```
var list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("Omni");
list.add("Okan");
var iter = list.iterator();
for (var item = iter.next(); iter.hasNext(); iter.next()) {
    System.out.println(item);
}
```

I tried this code and got `Omni Omni` instead of `Onmi Okan`. I tried also different sets of elements, but got the same problem - first element repeats `list.size()` times

Comment: You forgot to update the `item`. Also you are checking `hasNext()` after calling `next()`

Comment: this is not java, but javascript. I updated the tag

Comment: @user2342558 This is java, `var` is valid keyword since version 10.

Comment: @Chaosfire I see, so since v 10 it let use of `var` to automatically set the type by the one of the defined expression?

Comment: @user2342558 If I remember correctly the feature is called local variable type inference. Basically the compiler figures out the correct type during compilation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
        for (var item = iter.next(); iter.hasNext(); iter.next()) {
            System.out.println(item);
        }
```

You can use the following, but still not the best option:

```
        for (; iter.hasNext();) {
            System.out.println(iter.next());
        }
```

Best option is to use a while loop like this:

```
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(iter.next());
        }
```

The problem is in your for loop.

This is the structure of the for-loop

`for(initialization; exit condition; update variables)`

In your case, you used `var item = iter.next()` as the initializer, that means the `item` was initialized with the first value.
After that value was printed, as the `update variables` part, you did `iter.next()`, this returned the next value. But you never stored it.

After the `update variables`, it will check the exit condition. Since the 2nd value has been extracted, the `iter.hasNext()` will return false, so the for loop will exit. So, in your case, only ONE value was printed. 2nd value was just not stored in any variable. You could have done `item = iter.next()` as the update part, but still `item` would have been updated, but due to `iter.hasNext()` condition will return false just after update variables, it would not have been printed still.

Answer (score 3):

This will work:

```
var list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("Omni");
list.add("Okan");
for (var it = list.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
    var item = it.next();
    System.out.println(item);
}
```

However, it's not really the most reader-friendly way. There are other alternatives (Oleg already suggested one.) Take a look at some examples here: [Ways to iterate over a list in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18410035/ways-to-iterate-over-a-list-in-java)

The most straight-forward way is the enhanced for loop, like so:

```
var list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("Omni");
list.add("Okan");
for (var elem : list) {
    System.out.println(elem);
}
```

Comment: a little note: that is not Java but JavaScript. (btw they are very similar and both have the enhanced for loop)

Comment: This is indeed Java. The newer versions allow for the `var` keyword.

Comment: ooh I see, since v 10, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You use `for` loop incorectly. It's better to use `while` loop instead.

```java
List<String> items = List.of("Omni", "Okan");
Iterator<String> it = items.iterator();

while (it.hasNext()) {
    String item = it.next();
    System.out.println(item);
}
```